# How to prevent guest user to access admin page

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to prevent guest user to access admin page.
This is where I capture role `1 for admin` and `0 for guest`.

```html
 <%
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
String sessionVal= (String)session .getAttribute("loggedIn");
int role = (Integer)session .getAttribute("role");
System.out.println(" role "+ role);
if(sessionVal == null)
{
 response.sendRedirect("/project/pages/login.jsp");
}
else
{
%>
      // All html code goes here
```

This is `html` code for navigation

```html
<ul id="nav">
 <li><a href="/project/pages/home.jsp">Dashboard</a></li>
 <li ><a href="/project/pages/profile.jsp">Profile</a></li>     
 <li><a href="/project/pages/setting.jsp">Setting</a></li>         <li><a href="/project/pages/admin.jsp">Admin</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now How do I prevent guest user(`role == 0`) to access admin page. or `if role == 0` how do I hide `admin.jsp`.

Comment: you need interceptors

Comment: I am new to this, can u please elaborate bit

Comment: I am not aware of your project setup. But Filters are used for authentication purposes (among other). You can google them I am sure you will find plenty of explanations and examples

Comment: I suggest that you learn a framework like Struts, Spring MVC or Stripes and avoid at all cost having Java code in your JSP.  or at least have the code in a generic servlet and use filters.

Comment: look up Servlet Filters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not

```
if(sessionVal == null || role == 0)
```

to hide the link in JSP

```
    <%
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
int role = (Integer)session .getAttribute("role");
System.out.println(" role "+ role);
if(role != 0)
{
 %>
    <a href="admin.jsp">Top Secret Link</a>
 <%
}
```

Comment: if (role == 0) the user should be able to access all the pages instead admin.jsp

Comment: so if `role == 0` then redirect to some other page.  if `role == 0`, do not show the link to admin.jsp

Comment: yes you got it. But I am facing problem in not showing the link to admin.jsp

Answer (score 1):

One of many ways would be the following....

In the start of your admin.jsp page you can have something like this:

```
HttpSession monitorSession = request.getSession();
String sessionVal= (String)monitorSession.getAttribute("loggedIn");
int role = (Integer)monitorSession.getAttribute("role");

if(role ==0){ //make the check here
    response.sendRedirect("somePage.jsp");
}
```

also in the same way you can hide the option for the admin.jsp from your navigation

Comment: if(role ==0){ //make the check here
    response.sendRedirect("somePage.jsp");
}  if I do this guest will be able to see the admin.jsp, but I dont want guest to see the admin.jsp. How can I hide admin.jsp

Comment: use this to prevent access to the jsp and use @Scary Wombat answer to hide it from the menu, in that way he will not be able to access the admin.jsp

Answer (score 1):

you can in your jsp like this :

```
    <%
    String sessionVal= (String)session .getAttribute("loggedIn");
    int role = (Integer)session .getAttribute("role");
            if (sessioanVal == null || role == 0) {
    %>
        <li><a href="/project/pages/home.jsp">Dashboard</a></li> (simplle which you want to hide)

   <%
    } else {                            
   %>
      <li ><a href="/project/pages/profile.jsp">Profile</a></li>    
        (which you want to show)

  <%
     }
  %>
```